# Securing an entire directory with MVC 5 Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin

In the old form authentication, you could secure an entire directory with a web.config setting. I can't seem to figure out how to do this with the new OWIN authentication. It looks like it only works via attributes on controllers. I must be missing something. There must be a way to secure images, html, script etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Katana doesn't provide any authorization middleware, only authentication middleware, so it'd be up to you to implement your path based authorization and return 401 if you didn't like the user.

One way you could do this is to use app.Map("/yourfolder", ctx=>{
   // do your authorization check in here
});